# Make the elements in the grid appear one by one

Tags: list-manipulation, animation, grid-layouts

[image]
I need to make an animation like this, start with a table at first, then each element filled from left to right, top to bottom, instead of dynamically generating grid, the current code can only generate tables line by line, do you have a good way?

```
list = Table[Row@{b, " \[Times] ", a, " \[LongEqual] ", b a}, {a, 9}, {b, a}];
Grid[list]
Manipulate[Grid[list[[1 ;; n]], BaseStyle -> "Text", Frame -> All,
  FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.9]], {n, 1, 9, 1}]
```

More general, if it works for other irregular lists would be better

```
list=RandomInteger[10,#]&/@RandomInteger[{3,9},{9}]
Grid[list, Frame->All]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

A function that shows the data with a limited number:

```
ClearAll[limit];
limit[data_, limit_] := 
 Module[{counter = 1}, 
  MapIndexed[If[counter <= limit, counter++; #1, ""] &, data, {2}]]
```

Generate all the frames:

```
Table[Grid[
   limit[Table[
     Row@{b, " \[Times] ", a, " \[LongEqual] ", b a}, {a, 9}, {b, a}],
     i], BaseStyle -> "Text", Frame -> All, 
   FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.9], ItemSize -> {6, 1}], {i, 1, 45, 1}]
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
size = 9;
list = Table[
   Row[{b, " \[Times] ", a, " \[LongEqual] ", b a}], {a, size}, {b, 
    a}];
g = Table[Spacer[70], {size}, {size}];
Manipulate[
 tick;
 Module[{},
  g[[n, 1 ;; m]] = list[[n, 1 ;; m]];
  If[m < size,
   tick = Not[tick];
   If[m == n, m = 1; n++, m++];
   ];
  Pause[.5];
  Grid[g, BaseStyle -> "Text", Frame -> All, 
   FrameStyle -> GrayLevel[0.9]]
  ],
 Grid[{{Button[
     "Play again", {g = Table[Spacer[70], {size}, {size}];; n = 1; 
      m = 1; tick = Not[tick]}]}}]
 ,
 {{tick, False}, None},
 {{n, 1}, None},(*row number*)
 {{m, 1}, None},(*column number*)
 TrackedSymbols :> {tick}
 ]
```

To change speed, just change the `Pause` amount. It is left as an exercise to add a `stop` and `rewind` buttons.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I didn't say it clearly, I hope the grid is 9 by 9 at first, then each element filled from left to right, top to bottom

Comment: @matrix89 changed it so it shows each entry at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a grid with all elements styled `White`:

```
grid = Grid[Table[Style[Row[{Row@{i, "×", j}, i j},"="], 14, White], 
    {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, i}], Alignment -> "=", Dividers -> All];

indices = Position[grid, _Style];
```

We can use [`Clock`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clock.html)

[image]

to replace the style of one additional element from `White` to `Black` every 1/3 second:

```
clock := Clock[{0, 45, 1}, 45/3, 2]

Dynamic @ MapAt[# /. White -> Black &, indices[[;; clock]]] @ grid
```

[image]

Use `Clock[{0, 45, 1}, 45, 2]` to make a new element *appear* every second:

[image]

A similar approach is to wrap each grid element with `Invisible` and replace `Invisible` with `Identity` one cell at a time using `Clock`:

```
invisiblegrid = Grid[Table[Invisible @ Row[{Row@{i, "×", j}, i j}, "="], 
     {i, 1, 9}, {j, 1, i}], 
   Alignment -> "=", Dividers -> All, ItemStyle -> FontSize -> 14];

indexlist = Position[grid, _Invisible];

Dynamic @ MapAt[# /. Invisible -> Identity &, invisiblegrid, 
  indexlist[[;; Clock[{0, 45, 1}, 45, 2]]]]
```

> same picture as above